# Rotation of aircraft's body-frame

Tags: aerospace-engineering

There are Tait-Bryan angular changes $(\dot{\phi}, \dot{\theta}, \dot{\psi})$, which describe the angular change rates of the body-frame within the inertial frame (world frame).

And then there are angular change rates $(p,q,r)$ of the aircraft within its own body frame.

To convert these angular change rates between each other, a rotation matrix is needed.

$\begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \\ r \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -sin(\theta) \\ 0 & cos(\phi) & sin(\phi)cos(\theta) \\ 0 & -sin(\phi) & cos(\phi)cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \dot{\phi} \\ \dot{\theta} \\ \dot{\psi} \end{bmatrix}$

Why is that? Why aren't they exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When plane is flying north, roll axis goes from north to south.

When the plane is flying west the roll axis goes from west to east.

So no they are not the same.